# how to refresh activity from adapter when a record is deleted?

Tags: android, listview

i am using android studio in listview i have added adapter. when user click delete button from listview item then i want to refresh activity.

adapter delete button definition

```
    deletebtn =convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

    deletebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        databaseAccess.deleteFavorite(favoriteModel.getWid());

        }
    });
```

i have tried this code but not working

```
   deletebtn =convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

    deletebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        databaseAccess.deleteFavorite(favoriteModel.getWid());


            Intent intent1=new Intent(context,FavoriteNameslist.class);

            context.startActivity(intent1);
            ((Activity)context).finish();

        }
    });
```

i am new to Android - please help
i want when user click on delete button then refresh activity

Comment: just call notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: Data refresh in listview after deleting from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640658/android-data-refresh-in-listview-after-deleting-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call your Activity to referesh listview you can use

**`notifyDataSetChanged()`**

remove the item and set notifyDataSetChanged()

```
yourList.remove([INDEX]);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing a single item from the view, you need to call

```
yourAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position) //Just pass the position to this. This also has a default animation. Try this in your adapter class instead of refreshing the layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines of code on Deleting Row to Update adapter

```
 arrayList.remove(position);
 mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```